# Bootstrap Select All check box in apex:repeat

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have a page with bootstrap Checkbox. The select All is working fine, however each row wise select check box is not working properly. only first row checkbox is selected and unselected. If I click on any other row check box, it will check the first row checkbox only.

```
<table id="domainTable"> <!-- Added ID -->
<thead>
<tr>
   <th>         
         <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
           <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAllDomainList" checked=""/>
               <label for="selectAllDomainList">
                            Select All
                        </label>
         </div>
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
     <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/> 
          <apex:repeat value="{!accList}" var="e">  
               <tr> 
                  <td> 
                      <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                    <input id="Text{!rowNum}" type="checkbox" checked=""/>
                                    <label for="Text{!rowNum}">
                                        Primary
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>                                                                                                                         
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.name}" /></td>   
                        </tr>                                             
             <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/> 
       </apex:repeat>
</tbody>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>

  // on document ready
    jQuery(function($){  

        $('#selectAllDomainList').click (function () {
             var checkedStatus = this.checked;
            $('#domainTable tbody tr').find('td:first :checkbox').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
             });
        });
    });
```

Select All which is working

[image]

Individual row check box which is not working

[image]

Only first row i can select or deselect.

with WrapperList:

```
<tbody>
                         <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/> 
                              <apex:repeat value="{!wrapList}" var="e">  
                                   <tr> 
                                      <td> 
                                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                                        <input id="Text{!rowNum}" type="checkbox" checked=""/>
                                                        <label for="Text{!rowNum}">
                                                            Primary
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>                                                                                                                         

                                      <!--<td><apex:outputText value="{!e.name}" /></td>!-->   
                                          <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.name}" /></td>

                                            </tr>                                             
                                 <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{! rowNum + 1 }"/> 
                           </apex:repeat>
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you are using the same Id value for all of the checkboxes:

```
<input id="Text{!rowNum}" type="checkbox" checked=""/>
<label for="Text{!rowNum}">
```

because you are failing to increment the `rowNum` variable. So when any label is clicked on, it is the first checkbox with the Id that is selected.

To fix that change the `apex:variable` at the bottom of the loop to increment:

```
<apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{! rowNum + 1 }"/>
```

so the Id values are unique and the selection works.

Comment: Do you know why it is not working if the pass wrapperlist in repeat :

Comment: @Ajay You'll probably need to post another question with the changed code and detail of exactly what is not working.